# CAD tools are not enabled for the current map tool

Tags: qgis

When I click on Advanced Digitizing Panel, I get the message "CAD tools are not enabled for the current map tool"  What does this mean and how can I used the Advanced Digitizing tool?

I'm using QGIS 2.18.12

Comment: I think that tool depends on the layer you have selected and its geometry type, ie point line or polygon, and the various tools on that plugin toolbar only work on one of those types

Answer (score 5):

One possible issue is that your data is in geographic coordinates, and CAD tools can not work with geographic coordinates:

1. Enable editing
2. Add feature
3. Enable `Advanced Digitizing Panel`, and you will receive a message that

> CAD tools cannot be used with geographic coordinates. Change the
>   coordinates.

[image]

However, when working with projected coordinates data, it works perfectly:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There can be a couple of reasons. One is that the layer is not in edit mode. Another is that, if the layer is in edit mode, either no tool has been selected, or the Advanced Digitizing panel does not provide any functions for the selected tool.  If you "Add Feature" tool for a layer in edit mode you should see the Advanced Digitizing panel change to show options.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this problem whilst trying to move a layer imported as a DBF file exported from Illustrator. After converting the layer (to a SHP), the standard digitising tool bar became available. I then toggled the edit mode by clicking the pencil icon, and after selecting 'Move Features', the advanced CAD tools became available.